# HDMI tone output not working with PC audio but with test audio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

just at the beginning:

I'm not good in using Ubuntu (i've been using it for app. one moth) so please do not give me any unexplained instructions. Please do give me detailed information what i have do type in where, what buttons i have to press when and where i can find the options u mention.
I'm also not the best english speaker so i'd be thankfull if u don't mind of my spelling or gramma mistakes.

So here is my problem:
My PC is connected to my TV so i can use the bigger screen. However, it is not conn. diractly to my TV, but to my repeater (i don't know if this word is correct, i mean that big thing wich whith boxes and subwoofers are controlled). This "thing" than is conn. to my TV. That way, the "thing" filters the tone out and the TV just displayes the pictures. But if i try to start a video, i hear no audio. The picture is ok, but the tone is not working. If i open the tone options, i can choose between HDMI Output and my onbord Notebook speakers. I can also emit a test audio sequence wich is working properly. But as soon as i start a regular video or music, the tone is gone again.
When i used Windows on my Pc, everything worked fine, so i guess it my be a problem with some drivers or sth. like this.

I am using:

-Lenove Flex 14 (Laptop)

-Newest Ubuntu version

-Pioneer "repeater"

Thank u very much for your help ;)

Edit:
Some programs' audio works: In some games, my son installed, the audio works as intended via my receiver....
-Robocraft
-Minecraft

Answer (score 0):

Your repeater is actually called a receiver. The receiver controls your sources, your ins and outs. First thing you want to do is test the output of your Lenovo you will do this by connecting it directly to your TV HDMI port. You will want to see if you're getting picture and sound if you are then you can go back to connecting your laptop to the Pioneer receiver on the back of the receiver you will have a row of HDMI plugs choose the first available input. Your sound will now be processed by the speakers connected directly to the Pioneer receiver and not your TV your TV will not be used as a monitor and there will be an output that will send video to your TV choose the selected source connected from the house put of the Pioneer receiver into your first available input on the TV as long as the Pioneer receiver input if selected to the source connected from Villanova hiii HDMI 1 or HDMI 2. you should get your picture to the TV and sound through your surround sound. if you're not getting the sound through the surround sound you have a problem with the output connection from the speakers.